# Adding duplicate values in a text file in java

Tags: java

I want to add duplicate values in a text file with java. I am able to read the file but my only issue is adding the duplicate values.
Adding all the Count columns of duplicate values

Text file format:

> RunID|Segment|Count|FileName
> 6227|20210829|23983|CloudBI.DiscPromo.V.20210829.20210829061809_0.snappy.parquet
> **6230|20210829|292088|CloudBI.DiscPromo.V.20210829.20210829063202_3.snappy.parquet**
> 6229|20210829|1000000|CloudBI.DiscPromo.V.20210829.20210829062106_1.snappy.parquet
> 6232|20210829|32260|CloudBI.DiscPromo.V.20210829.20210829065128_0.snappy.parquet
> **6230|20210829|1000000|CloudBI.DiscPromo.V.20210829.20210829063202_1.snappy.parquet**
> 6228|20210829|571414|CloudBI.DiscPromo.V.20210829.20210829061829_0.snappy.parquet
> **6230|20210829|1000000|CloudBI.DiscPromo.Delta.20210829.20210829063202_0.snappy.parquet**
> 6229|20210829|326235|CloudBI.DiscPromo.Delta.20210829.20210829062106_2.snappy.parquet
> 6231|20210829|689576|CloudBI.DiscPromo.Delta.20210829.20210829064805_0.snappy.parquet
> 6229|20210829|1000000|CloudBI.DiscPromo.Delta.20210829.20210829062106_0.snappy.parquet
> **6230|20210829|1000000|CloudBI.DiscPromo.Delta.20210829.20210829063202_2.snappy.parquet**

```
for (File file : filesList) {
    String filename = file.getName();

    if (filename.endsWith(".txt")) {
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String input;
        sc.nextLine();
        while (sc.hasNext()) {

            input = sc.nextLine();
            if (input.length() > 0) {
                String[] data = input.split("\\|", 0);
                if (!(data[2].equals(null))) {
                    String fullDeltaPath = directoryPath + "\\" + data[3];

                    for (String name: testt) {
                        name = data[3].substring(data[3].indexOf("_", data[3].indexOf("_") + 1) + 1, data[3].lastIndexOf("_"));
                    }

                    if (hashSetRuID.add(data[0]) == false && (hashSetFilename.add(testt) == false)) {
                        if ((hashSetFilename.containsAll(testt))  && (hashSetRuID.contains(data[0]) == true)) {
System.out.println(testt.length() + "Tesss" + "File Count:" + data[2] + ": Run ID: " + data[0]);
                        } else {
                            // System.out.println(testt + "Something something" + "File Count:" + data[2] + ": Run ID: " + data[0]);
                        }

                    } else {
                        // System.out.println("Else Part File Name: " + testt+ ":  File Count: " + data[2] + ": Run ID: " + data[0]);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("File");
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Empty File with no data");
            }
        }
        sc.close();
        System.out.println("File empty");
```

Tried using Hashmaps but I am not getting all the duplicates

Comment: if `hashSetFilename` is a [`java.util.Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) that's probably part of your problem

Comment: A `java.util.Map` with its `merge()` function might be the right thing to use in your case. With this you can easily update or add the value, depending on whether the key already exists in the map or not. You could for example map `data[0]` or `testt` to the number of times they occur.